# Angular HTTP get response not the same as what network tab shows

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having an intermittent issue in that when I make a call via the Angular HTTP service:

```
        return $http({
        url: '/campaign/' + campaignId,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            response.data.hardcode = dfltValues.hardcode;

            response.data.endDate = new Date(response.data.endDate).toISOString();
            response.data.startDate = new Date(response.data.startDate).toISOString();

            return response;
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
    );
```

What's weird is that every 10th time or so when I refresh the page some of the values are coming back as undefined, yet the network tab says that all the values came through correctly. Also this seems to only be happening on Chrome. I haven't been able to reproduce in FF/IE/Safari. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue to be a plugin I was using called angularjs-slider, I threw a watcher on the variables that were affected and found that they were defined correctly coming in, but then right away were set to undefined. I switched out the plugin to just use the standard input type of "range" and everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I went into similar issue months ago. Try to disable cache on IE and see if it happen on IE also.

If so, you issue maybe came from back-end does not return valid data all the time. (IE etc. use cache instead of calling back-end in most of the time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm using chrome with the developer tools set to disable cache and it's still happening. The annoying part is that I have to refresh 20 times to get it to happen once, and chrome appears to be the only browser having the issue :(

Comment: I think you need to find out is a front-end issue or back-end issue first. There is a Chrome extension called Postman, you can use it to fire backend calls. Try to use this extension to fire a lots of api calls and see if the issue comes out first. :)